# ¿Como especificar el menu que desplegara el boton con la clase Dropdown de Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, menú

Estoy realizando un proyecto de YouTube y estoy creando los botones que aparecen a la par de subir video y tengo dos menus que se mostraran al hacer click en cada uno de ellos, el problema es que al darle click al boton "btn-opc" me muestra el mismo menu que "btn-apps" y quiero que me muestre el otro menu. Aqui esta el codigo de los menus.

```html
<button class="btn btn-light btn-circle end-btn" type="button" id="btn-apps" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Apps de Youtube">
    <i class="fas fa-th fa-lg"></i>
</button>
<!-- Menu de dropdown de las apps de YouTube-->
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btn-apps">
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-tv.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube TV
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-gaming.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube Gaming
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-music.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube Music
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-kids.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube Kids
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-icon.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> Academia de Creadores
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-icon.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> Youtube para Artistas
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-light btn-circle end-btn" type="button" id="btn-opc" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Configruacion">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i>
</button>
<!--Menu dropdown de las configuraciones de YT-->
<div class="dropdown-menu p-2" aria-labelledby="btn-opc">
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <i class="fas fa-cog fa-lg ml-2 mr-3"></i> Configuracion
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-lg ml-2 mr-3"></i> Ayuda
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <i class="fas fa-comment fa-lg ml-2 mr-3"></i> Enviar comentarios
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1 dropright" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4 dropdown-toggle">
      Idioma: Español
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1 dropright" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4 dropdown-toggle">
      Ubicacion: Estados Unidos
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1 dropright" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4 dropdown-toggle">
      Modo Restringido: Desactivado
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que cada botón despliegue su respectivo menú, debes poner a cada uno de ellos dentro de un contenedor con la clase "dropdown":

```
<div class="dropdown">
  --botón 1 y menú 1--
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  --botón 2 y menú 2--
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-light btn-circle end-btn" type="button" id="btn-apps" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Apps de Youtube">
    <i class="fas fa-th fa-lg"></i>
</button>
<!-- Menu de dropdown de las apps de YouTube-->
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btn-apps">
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-tv.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube TV
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-gaming.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube Gaming
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-music.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube Music
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-kids.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> YouTube Kids
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-icon.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> Academia de Creadores
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <img src="img\assets\yt-icon.png" class=" ml-2 mr-3"> Youtube para Artistas
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-light btn-circle end-btn" type="button" id="btn-opc" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Configruacion">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i>
</button>
<!--Menu dropdown de las configuraciones de YT-->
<div class="dropdown-menu p-2" aria-labelledby="btn-opc">
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <i class="fas fa-cog fa-lg ml-2 mr-3"></i> Configuracion
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-lg ml-2 mr-3"></i> Ayuda
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4">
      <i class="fas fa-comment fa-lg ml-2 mr-3"></i> Enviar comentarios
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1 dropright" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4 dropdown-toggle">
      Idioma: Español
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1 dropright" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4 dropdown-toggle">
      Ubicacion: Estados Unidos
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-block p-0 pt-2 pb-1 dropright" href="#">
    <div class="pl-2 pr-4 dropdown-toggle">
      Modo Restringido: Desactivado
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo